# Как сделать привелегии для определенного пользователя?

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте!Недавно начал изучать Laravel и решил в этих целях заняться написанием блога.
В блоге уже есть система аутентификации пользователей (из коробки), вывод статей и форма для их написания.Хотелось бы ограничить написание статей из формы,а точнее дать такую возможность лишь администратору.В документации прочитал про метод loginUsingId и решил его использовать вот так:

```
@if (Auth::loginUsingId(1)) //где 1 - id администратора
    <li><a href="{{url('/createpost')}}">Создать статью</a</li>  
@endif
```

С таким кодом данный пользователь просто при заходе на страницу аутентифицировался автоматически,причем выйти было невозможно.Похоже понял я данный метод немного не так и неправильно его использую.Подскажите пожалуйста решение проблемы.Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если делать не красиво и не правильно попробуйте проверять `@if(Auth::user()->id == 1)` - для этого должно в модели быть прописан доступ к полю таблицы, смотрите свойство `$fillable`. Но все-же советую разобраться и сделать правильно

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ, сделал проверку как вы и написали, может и не красиво и не правильно, но хотя бы проверка заработала, уже радует! :)Попробую получше разобраться с этой темой попозже, еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, метод которым вы пробовали воспользоватся предназначен для входа в систему по *ID*, но не для проверки.

Для того чтоб **организовать проверку прав** пользователя, вам нужно эти права ему **назначить**, а тут у вас два пути, *писать свой велосипед*, или использовать одно из *готовых решений*.

Если будете **писать сами**  то сделайте таблицу прав и модель для нее, свяжите их с пользователем с помощью eloquent связей, и свободно проверяйте в любом месте назначены ли права пользователю. *Пример реализации можете подсмотреть в первом паке.*

**Или воспользуйтесь одним из паков:**

[Более базоваый вариант, который поддерживает прямую привязку прав к пользователю](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

[Вариант посложнее с привязкой прав к роли, а роль уже в свою очередь назначается пользователю](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#checking-for-roles--permissions)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Dust0 Если один из ответов считаете правильным отметьте его как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#creating-policies), которые идут из коробки.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял вам нужна система админки, Если да то создайте middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware Admin
```

И в функцию handle добавьте это

```
if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect('/home');
```

Так же создайте Контроллер

```
php artisan make:controller AdminController
```

Откройте этот контроллер и замените этим кодом

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('admin');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.home');
    }
}
```

После перейдите в

> app\http\Kernel.php

и добавьте в `protected $routeMiddleware` строчку `'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,`
Получаем что то типа этого:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

> Откройте app\User.php и добавьте функцию

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->admin;//в таблице users обязательно должно быть колонка `admin`
}
```

Так же вам необходимо добавить в таблицу users колонку `admin` или же в папке

> datebase/migrations/create_users_table.php

после `$table->string('password');` добавить `$table->integer('admin')->nullable();` и выполнить команду `php artisan migrate`

> Откройте routes/web.php

и добавьте это`Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');`

Создайте в resoures/views/

> admin/home.blade.php//внутри файла вставьте любой текст.

В базе данных дайте себе админку и перейдите по ссылке [you-app.dev/admin](http://you-app.dev/admin)
покажет ваш текст в admin/home.blade.php или же переадресует назад в [you-app.dev/home](http://you-app.dev/home)
Это в том случай если вам нужен панель для администратора

если же вы просто хотите ограничить права, создайте в таблице users колонку admin и в

> app/User.php

Вставьте

```
public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->admin;//в таблице users обязательно должно быть колонка `admin`
    }
```

Вот вам и ограничение, а проверить права можно так `@if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())`

Comment: Я бы **не рекомендовал** рассматривать этот вариант, *он подходит только если нужно на вчера* и есть уверенность что в системе будет **только одна роль** (админ), Если потом нужно будет добавить еще несколько вариантов доступа придется переписывать много кода... *Уже сталкивался с подобной реализацией.* И лишнее подымание таблицы юзеров тоже не лучший вариант, она чаще всего самая тяжеловесная.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ, попробую разобраться!